# Python can't locate module files from other directory

Tags: python

I have a project structured as follow:

```
project\
   __init__.py
   gui\
      __init__.py
      gui_file_one.py
      gui_file_two.py
   logic\
      __init__.py
      logic_file_one.py
      logic_file_two.py
```

Let's say that in a `gui_file_one.py` I need to import class A that is located in a `logic_file_one.py`. When I try to do from `logic.logic_file_one import A` I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logic'`. How do I overcome this? How should this class be imported?

Comment: Please show some code to go with your verbal description.

Comment: Can you add your importing statement? And how you run your script, directly or by calling it from another location?

Comment: I think this question have [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)